# One word substitution for "Pin drop silence"

Tags: single-word-requests

Many time we hear this phrase but I'm wondering if there exists a single word for this.

Comment: *Silence* alone connotes absolute absence of sound. It works.

Comment: Yes, it's called "silence."

Comment: @cobaltduck , sir, can I say "The room is pindrop silent"?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it is hard to see that the word we've been looking for was right in front of us the whole time.

***Pin drop silence*** emphasizes the *degree* of silence, suggesting that the silence is so absolute or complete that one can hear a pin drop.

Now consider the definition of ***[silence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/silence)***:

> *Complete* absence of sound.

Thus, *silence* alone connotes absolute absence of sound. It works as a replacement for *pin drop silence*.

You can view *pin drop silence* on analogy with *utter vacuity* (here, *utter* is a bit redundant since *vacuity* is already pretty absolute). *Pin drop* acts as a modifier of degree, just like *utter*. But when the word its modifying already has a degree "built in" (as *silence* does, evinced by the presence of *complete* in the definition above), the modifier can be dropped without much loss. Note, however, that *pin drop* might carry some connotations: For example, that the situation is tense. Such connotations would be lost by dropping it.

People regularly say **It's so *quiet* you can hear a pin drop.** They do *not* regularly say **It's so *silent* you can hear a pin drop**. This is because *quiet* is less absolute than *silence*. Using the modifier makes sense with *quiet*, but not with *silence*.

Comment: That leaves the question what is *absolute silence*? Unless describing outer space there are almost always some sort of background noises. That is probably why there are so many paraphrasing possibilities for the total silence. For [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silence) it's just **a lack of sound or noise**. That does not sound as total as the oxford definition.

Comment: @Helmar, we definitely do use "silence" to mean the *relative* absence of sound, rather than the more theoretical *absolute absence* of sound. No doubt about it. Typical speakers probably aren't informed enough on the physics of sound to even conceive of the absolute conception. But *silence* definitely connotes a more total state than *quiet*, which is why (I imagine), *some* dictionaries use the modifier *complete*.

Comment: I generally agree. And as a one-word request **silence** seems to be the best option. I just wanted to point out why often a paraphrasation is used to - well describe the degree of silence. Besides (tense) situations where the silence is just one part of the description.